# Energy level diagrams with TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Do you have any experience with creating `energy level diagrams` with TeX as shown below ?

What software/packages would you recommend me ?

I've heard about TikZ, but I don't have any experience with it and I would prefer something easy to handle or more WISIWYG.

I would like to illustrate `Hund rules`, `Zeeman splitting` and some related physical effects with option to customize pictures.

Hopefully this isn't too much off-topic question.
Cheers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Examples for Energy level diagrams Links**:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/atomic/imgato/mulelec2.gif
http://mxp.physics.umn.edu/s05/projects/s05rb/images/Image173.gif
http://www.webexhibits.org/causesofcolor/images/content/15z.jpg

Comment: All certainly doable (see for example the  [`modiagram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/modiagram) package, which does atomic/molecular orbitals), but 'easy to handle' will depend on your requirements. Perhaps you could illustrate what sort of input you are hoping to use so we can gauge how easy this might be.

Comment: It would be nice of you to show us some diagrams you are talking about or at least link us to good Wikipedia pages or other references so that we could at least see what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, here are some examples http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/atomic/imgato/mulelec2.gif http://mxp.physics.umn.edu/s05/projects/s05rb/images/Image173.gif  http://www.webexhibits.org/causesofcolor/images/content/15z.jpg

Comment: Have you checked out [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/energy-level-diagram/)?

Comment: @DocBuckets: These examples might be even more excessive: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fluor-energy-levels/ http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/hydrogen-splitting/

Comment: I'm quite certain that something very much like your picture is around here, but I can't seem to find it...  [Found it!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13863/molecular-orbital-diagrams-in-latex)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Remarks

I implemented the first diagram in Ti*k*Z. All the coloring stuff has been outsourced to `\tikzset` so it is easy to change the style of the drawing.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\tikzset{
    level/.style = {
        ultra thick,
        blue,
    },
    connect/.style = {
        dashed,
        red
    },
    notice/.style = {
        draw,
        rectangle callout,
        callout relative pointer={#1}
    },
    label/.style = {
        text width=2cm
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw all levels
    \draw[level] (0,0) -- node[above] {4p4d} (2,0);

    \draw[connect] (2,0) -- (3,-2) (2,0) -- (3,3);
    \draw[level] (3,3) -- node[above] {$S=0$} node[below] {(Singlets)} (5,3);
    \draw[level] (3,-2) -- node[above] {$S=1$} node[below] {(Triplets)} (5,-2);

    \draw[connect] (5,3) -- (6,4.5) (5,3) -- (6,3.5) (5,3) -- (6,1.5);
    \draw[connect] (5,-2) -- (6,-0.5) (5,-2) -- (6,-1.5) (5,-2) -- (6,-3.5);
    \draw[level] (6,4.5) -- node[above] {${}^1P$} (8,4.5);
    \draw[level] (6,3.5) -- node[above] {${}^1D$} (8,3.5);
    \draw[level] (6,1.5) -- node[above] {${}^1F$} (8,1.5);
    \draw[level] (6,-0.5) -- node[above] {${}^3P$} (8,-0.5);
    \draw[level] (6,-1.5) -- node[above] {${}^3D$} (8,-1.5);
    \draw[level] (6,-3.5) -- node[above] {${}^3F$} (8,-3.5);

    \draw[connect] (8,4.5) -- (9,4.5) (8,3.5) -- (9,3.5) (8,1.5) -- (9,1.5);
    \draw[level] (9,4.5) -- (11,4.5) node[right] {${}^1P_1$};
    \draw[level] (9,3.5) -- (11,3.5) node[right] {${}^1D_2$};
    \draw[level] (9,1.5) -- (11,1.5) node[right] {${}^1F_3$};

    \draw[connect] (8,-0.5) -- (9,-0.5) (8,-0.5) -- (9,-0.8) (8,-0.5) -- (9,-1)
        (8,-1.5) -- (9,-1.6) (8,-1.5) -- (9,-1.8) (8,-1.5) -- (9,-1.3)
        (8,-3.5) -- (9,-3.8) (8,-3.5) -- (9,-3.6) (8,-3.5) -- (9,-3.1);
    \foreach \i/\j in {2/-0.5, 1/-0.8, 0/-1} {
        \draw[level] (9,\j) -- (11,\j) node[right] {\scriptsize $\i$};
    }
    \node[level,right] at (11.5,-0.8) {${}^3P_{0,1,2}$};
    \foreach \i/\j in {3/-1.3, 2/-1.6, 1/-1.8} {
        \draw[level] (9,\j) -- (11,\j) node[right] {\scriptsize $\i$};
    }
    \node[level,right] at (11.5,-1.6) {${}^3D_{1,2,3}$};
    \foreach \i/\j in {4/-3.1, 3/-3.6, 2/-3.8} {
        \draw[level] (9,\j) -- (11,\j) node[right] {\scriptsize $\i$};
    }
    \node[level,right] at (11.5,-3.6) {${}^3F_{2,3,4}$};

    % Draw labels
    \node[label] at (4,5.5) {Spin-spin interaction};
    \node[label] at (7,5.5) {Orbit-orbit interaction};
    \node[label] at (10,5.5) {Spin-orbit interaction};

    % Draw annotations
    \node[notice={(0.5,0.5)},text width=1.5cm] at (2,-3) {Hunds rule \# 1};
    \node[notice={(0,1)}] at (4,-4) {Why is triplet lower};
    \node[notice={(0.7,0.7)},text width=3cm] at (6,-5) {Why is higher angular momentum state lower energy?};
    \node[notice={(-0.9,0.9)},text width=1.5cm] at (9,-5) {Hunds rule \# 2};
    \node[notice={(-0.2,1.6)},text width=3cm] at (11,-6.5) {Why is low total angular momentum state lower in energy?};
    \node[notice={(-0.5,0.5)},text width=1.5cm] at (12,-5) {Hunds rule \# 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Wow, it looks pretty cool, thank you very much